# Make Synchronous database operation asynchronous

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6, asp.net-4.5

I want to use bulk database operations in Asp.Net MVC 4.5.2 app.
There is good lib `Z.EntityFramework.Extensions`, but it costs 800$.
And free lib `EF.BulkExtensions`, but it doesn't contains async methods.
Question: if I will do this trick

```
await Task.Run(() => 
{ 
    MyDatabaseContext.BulkUpdate(entities); 
});
```

Will it work the same as if i used the async method (in terms of working with IIS' thread pool ) ?

Comment: [EF.BulkExtensions](https://github.com/borisdj/EFCore.BulkExtensions) *does* have a `BulkUpdateAsync`. There's no `bulk update` or `delete` in reality though, only BULK INSERT (ie inserting lots of data with minimal logging). All libraries that talk about "bulk updates" actually generate a SQL command in the background that typically sends the data as a table-valued type or part of a MERGE command.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos no, it doesn't have async. I'm using EF.BulkExtensions.1.4.2 with .netframework 4.5.2.
Your link points to EFCore  lib. I'll try to upgrade framework version.

Comment: EFCore  compatible with net framework 4.6+ and EF.Core 3+.
But I have dependency on EntityFramework.extenDED, which is depends on simple entity framework

Comment: Don't use that method then. There's no BULK UPDATE command that behaves the way `BULK INSERT` does, ie using minimal logging to insert data in the fastest way possible. What every library claiming to do "bulk updated" does, is generate a plain-old, fully logged `UPDATE` command that somehow joins with the new data, either in the form of a table-value parameter or data in a `VALUES` clause. Neither of these options can make good use of indexes which results in suboptimal performance and just doesn't scale to a large number of rows

Comment: It would be a lot faster if you inserted the rows into a staging table using `SqlBulkCopy` and then performed an UPDATE on the target that joined with the staging table ie `UPDATE target SET .... FROM target inner join staging on staging.ID=target.ID`.

Comment: In any case this is a long running operation that *shouldn't* be performed by an action. It should be handled as a background task using eg `QueueBackgroundWorkItem`. Check [How to run Background Tasks in ASP.NET](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/how-to-run-background-tasks-in-aspnet)

Answer (score 0):

You should at least do something like:

```
var task = new Task(() => { MyDatabaseContext.BulkUpdate(entities) }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
await task;
```

This ensures, that your task runs in its own thread and doesn't occupy a task from the task pool.